# Group readable cron jobs a security risk?

Tags: security, permissions, cron

I was just wondering, is using a cron job that is group readable a security risk? In this case, the script is chmod 755, and the group is basically a group of the sysadmins on the machine. The permissions seem to be fine, but I'm just wondering whether it's a bad idea to keep this script in a group or world readable place because it's a backup script that needs to be run as root. Thanks!

Comment: Sysadmin Mantra: Security is a matter of trust!

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. This is kind of a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real security risk I can think of off the top of my head is that if there is a security hole in the script, it can potentially be found by anyone just by reading the script.

However, if the script must be run as root, why do the group and user also have the executable bit set? IMO, the "correct" permissions for the file would be `740`, not `755` (so that the sysadmin group can read the file w/o `sudo`)

Comment: Hmm, OK. That makes sense. My question was kind of silly I guess.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what the script is. If the script contains passwords or other sensitive data then yes it probably is, otherwise, not so much.

Would you post the script on your office noticeboard? Would you post it on this website? If yes then it's fine for it to be readable by anyone, otherwise you should consider changing the permissions.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. It doesn't have any passwords because root is set up with a .pgpass file that will allow root to access the postgress databases without authenticating. It just seemed a little weird to me but I guess there's no problem with it.